# import and export function javascript electron

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, function, electron

I am trying to export a function from dom.js to login.js. Please can someone tell me why this is not working?
Below is from the dom.js file

```
export function rerenderAll  (){
methods.renderProfile();
methods.renderCalled();
methods.settings.settingsSideBar.renderSettings(userSettings,$settingsListUsers);
methods.settings.settingsSideBar.renderSettings(appSettings, $settingsListApp);
methods.renderPeople(dummyPinnedPeople);
methods.renderSearchRecents();
document.getElementById('settings-main-container').innerHTML = settingsPageDataUsers[0];

$pinnedBtn.style.backgroundColor = clickedheader;

}
```

this is in the login.js file

```
import {rerenderAll} from './dom.js';
console.log("running");
```

the console does not run and the program freezes there.

Comment: what does your folder structure look like and what are you using to compile, if anything (e.g. webpack, typescript, babel, etc.)

Comment: One minor thing to fix is you should not specify the file extension in the import e.g. `import {rerenderAll} from './dom'`